# How to match exact column value that will vary

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL I need to query a table that has a column of stock items identified via a combination of alpha and numeric code.  Each of these is in a seperate column, so I could have multiples of same or different alpha codes and also corresponding numerics.  In turn these are linked to a client order table.

What's the best way to query and return results where all stock items per client order have the same alpha code?

The stockitem alpha values will vary from one order to another so there is no static value that I am matching to. I'm thinking I would need to validate the first stockitemalpha value found and match it against all remaining stockitemalpha's found linked to specific clientorderid?

```
co.clientordersreference    | si.stockitemalpha
------------------------------------------------
1234                        | aaa
1234                        | aaa
1234                        | bbb
4343                        | ccc
4343                        | ccc
5454                        | ddd
5454                        | mmm
```

Data is returning as:

```
co.clientordersreference    | si.stockitemalpha |  stockitemalphacount 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1234                        | aaa               |  1
1234                        | bbb               |  1
4343                        | ccc               |  1
5454                        | ddd               |  1
5454                        | ccc               |  1
5454                        | mmm               |  1
```

whereas I'm expecting a result where the count is applied per clientorderreference, eg:

```
co.clientordersreference    | stockitemalphacount
------------------------------------------------
1234                        | 2
4343                        | 1
5454                        | 3
```

My initial query is along the the lines of:

```
Select co.clientordersreference, si.stockaitemalpha

from clientorders co, stockitem si
where co.id = si.id
and distinct(si.stockitemalpha) -- this is criteria I'm unsure of

group by co.clientordersreference
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated question, you can try aggregating over client orders and taking the distinct count of stock items.

```
SELECT
    co.clientordersreference,
    COUNT(DISTINCT si.stockitemalpha) AS COUNT(DISTINCT si.stockitemalpha)
FROM clientorders co
INNER JOIN stockitem si
    ON co.id = si.id
GROUP BY
    co.clientordersreference
```

Comment: Thank you, I did try this but it flagged a count of 1 to any multiples of the same stockitemalpha, but not a distinct count for each existence of a new stockitemalpha for a single clientorderreference

If i my data looked like this, 
co.clientordersreference   si.stockitemalpha
1234        aaa
1234        aaa
1234        bbb
4343        ccc
4343        ccc
5454        ddd
5454        mmm
5454        mmm
5454        mmm

Results:

ClientRef  StockItemAlpha  #Count
1234   aaa     1
1234   bbb     1
4343   ccc     1
5454   ddd     1
5454   mmm     1

Comment: @MattM Please _edit_ your question and include this sample data along with the output you expect.  You're not going to get any help dumping a table into a comment.

Comment: We're going nowhere fast.  _Update_ your question and show us a _table_ containing your data.

Comment: Sorry Tim, new to forum and realised error but had to go on call before could correct.  Hope update is clearer. Cheers!

Comment: many thanks, this achieved what I needed and also helped to breakdown where I had gone wrong in initial attempts.  Cheers!